# Does perf work on Red Hat 6.7?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, linux-kernel, perf

My company is stuck on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7. Running `perf record ls` as non-root results in an error: "Perf session creation failed."

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid
1
$ uname -r
2.6.32-573.51.1.e16.x86_64
```

It works on Redhat 6.4. There was a [patch to linux](https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/9/27/26) a while ago, but I can't tell if that was ported to Redhat 6.7.